# Mumford's vector bundle stability equivalent the notion orbit stability for a G-space?

Tags: vector-bundles, stability

Everyone seems to use the slope definition of stability for vector bundles without making any mention to the fact that this should be the correct definition describing that a stable equivalence class of vector bundles is then equivalent to a stable orbit under the action of the gauge group on say, the space of all connections.

Edit:

To be more precise, The notion of a stable orbit of a group action requires that, say, the stabilizer of an element be discrete. Now, viewing vector bundles as isomorphism classes under the action of the gauge group, one says that a vector bundle is stable if it satisfies the slope condition (all sub-bundles have strictly less slope). The question is, how is this slope inequality equivalent to the definition of stable orbit for group actions.

Comment: "this should be the correct definition": what is here "this"? Could you edit the language of your question? I have difficoulties understanding it. It is fine if you use more than one sentence...

Comment: Okie, I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is now up to snuff.